# Get ROWID using INNER JOIN Python SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying get number column using INNER JOIN

```
SELECT rowid, * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.name= table2.ID
WHERE name= "name"
```

It does't work.

How can i get rowid with joining two table?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should point from which table is should be taken? Something like this:

```sql
SELECT t1.rowid, t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.name = t2.ID
WHERE t1.name = "name"
```